# Choose between map+inner loop and flatMapValues+reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data like following in pairRDD, and I would like to collect a map with username as key, and sum of each list as value. The number of users is very large say 100m+, and lists are <1k in size. There are 2 choices I can think of - mapToPair and sum list with a simple for loop inside mapToPair, or flatMapValues the list to create `<user, value>` pairs then reduceBykey. Which is way is better?

```
Seq(
  ("user1",List(8,2,....)),
  ("user2",List(1,12,.....)),
  ...
  ("userN",List(99,5,...))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess `rdd.mapValues(_.sum)` would be faster because you iterate over the elements once instead of twice (once to flatten, once to reduce).

But the best answer would be to just test it an see.

Best tip I can think of though, is try to work with DataFrames or Datasets (Spark SQL) to begin with. If you end up with a flattened DataFrame you can call `df.groupBy($"user").agg(F.sum($"value"))` or if you have a Dataframe like the RDD you described you can just use the `aggregate` SQL function